# ReactJs, NodeJs, Mongodb Authentification

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I work on an application using React, Nodejs and Mongodb.
I have 2 tables for 2 differents user types on my database.
I was wondering if I should create one or 2 login pages on my frontend knowing that I have 2 different routes for the 2 types of users in my API.

What is the best solution according to you ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

if the data u want is same for both type of users, just create one login page in frontend and while sending the data to backend(i.e post method), conditionally change the api endpoints based on the user type.